# Can i set css class for table via TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, table

I'm using TinyMCE plugin. And now i need to set css class for table. I found some info on http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:table_class_list . But how can i apply it in TinyMCE plugin for wordpress?
Or there is some better solution for setting css class for table in TinyMCE?

Comment: This question **should be reopened**. TinyMCE is the main WP wysiwyg ***BUILT-IN*** editor, that is hella specific to WordPress and definitely not a generic question. As a case law I am putting this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120831/how-to-add-custom-css-theme-option-to-tinymce?rq=1
...and this question didn't even recieve appropriate answer...

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a custom plugin, but lot of effort.

I like the way about css in the front end.
[image]

The table button in TinyMCE creates a default table, without classes, like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below a simple example to format this for different colors in each raw.

```
table{
    color: #111;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2px auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}
table td{ 
    padding: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
/* provide some minimal visual accomodation for IE8 and below */
table tr{
    background: #eee;
}
/*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
table tr:nth-child(odd){ 
    background: #eee;
}
/*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
table tr:nth-child(even){
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not good solution. Not all users are familiar with css. If user know it - he can open code editor and simply set class="table-class".
So better have some prepared classes in style.css. And user just set required class and table is ready.

Comment: I thing is not a good idea, that authors work with CSS classes. She should work on content. Also a problem is, that you have the classes in the content, in the database. The difference between layout and content is important for maintenance. But you can add a option select with custom CSS classes to the tinymce. You find this solution in a other answer from my user here on wpse.